# cannot find local variable call in Android Studio

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a problem in my android studio project. when i try to do some retrieve API using retrofit from my web services, i had some errors that said

> "Cannot find local variable call"

here is my code :

```
private void RegisUserTampung(String token)
{
    Call<ResponseRegister> call = client.regisAccount("bearer " +token, "N", new Gson().toJson(regisUser));

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseRegister>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseRegister> call, Response<ResponseRegister> response) {
            ResponseRegister responseRegister = response.body();
            if (responseRegister != null) {
                Toast.makeText(VerifActivity.this, responseRegister.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseRegister> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(VerifActivity.this, "Failed POST Token to server ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and this is error i had when i went into debug mode :

> Cannot find local variable 'call'

any idea for this issue?

Comment: Can you post the logs. Try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

You Now Have 2 variable  With Same Name

```
Call<ResponseRegister> **call** = client.regisAccount("bearer " +token, "N", new Gson().toJson(regisUser));
```

And

```
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseRegister> **call**, Response<ResponseRegister>
```

try to change Variable Name